# null control for java server faces el

Tags: java, jsf

I cannot figure out how to do a null check withing a jsf attribute.
Here is the error message I get:
`value="#{configTableBean.selectedRecord != null ? configTableBean.selectedRecord.description : ''}": Illegal Syntax for Set Operation`

what is the proper way of checking for null?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You're apparently attempting to avoid `PropertyNotFoundException: base is null`. You cannot do it that way. You need to preinstantiate the nested bean in the constructor or `@PostConstruct` of the managed bean.

```
public class ConfigTableBean {
    private SomeOtherBean selectedRecord;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        this.selectedRecord = new SomeOtherBean();
    }

    // ...
}
```